# Regex: Only accept integer and empty string but no other symbols like (+ , -, . etc)

Tags: regex

I want a regex in javascript which only accept integers and empty string and no other symbols or special characters like (+ , -, .) or others.

I have found some regex but they accept symbols like +, - and . for example:

```
/^[0-9 ]*$/
/^[\d ]*$/
```

Please help me to find it. Thank you.

Comment: Just `^\d*$` or  `^[0-9]*$`

Comment: No, it is not possible unless you use it in an `input` element with `type="number"` in HTML. Use with `type="text"`.

Comment: Its working with text. Thank you.